# Glass Mapper GetLayoutItem depreciated method

Tags: glass-mapper

We are updating GlassMapper from 4 to 5.

Since the GlassController is depreciated in new version and we have used `GetLayoutItem` in many places. Can it be replaced with `MvcContext.GetContextItem` from MVCContext class?

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*GlassView* and *GlassController* got deprecated since v5.
Have a look at Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.IMvcContext, you should now be using the methods provided there to get the datasource, context and rendering items:

[image]

I hope it helps you.